# What does "Client" exactly mean for Hadoop / HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I understand the general concept behind it, but I would like more clarification and a clear-cut definition of what a "client" is.

For example, if I just write an hdfs command on the Terminal, is it still a "client" ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`Client`** in Hadoop refers to the Interface used to communicate with the Hadoop Filesystem. There are different type of Clients available with Hadoop to perform different tasks.

The basic filesystem client **`hdfs dfs`** is used to connect to a Hadoop Filesystem and perform basic file related tasks. It uses the ClientProtocol to communicate with a NameNode daemon, and connects directly to DataNodes to read/write block data.
To perform administrative tasks on HDFS, there is **`hdfs dfsadmin`**. For HA related tasks, **`hdfs haadmin`**. 
There are similar clients available for performing **YARN** related tasks.

These Clients can be invoked using their respective CLI commands from a node where Hadoop is installed and has the necessary configurations and libraries required to connect to a Hadoop Filesystem. Such nodes are often referred as Hadoop Clients.

> For example, if I just write an hdfs command on the Terminal, is it
>   still a "client" ?

Technically, **Yes**. If you are able to access the FS using the `hdfs` command, then the node has the configurations and libraries required to be a Hadoop Client.

**PS:** APIs are also available to create these Clients programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Edge nodes are the interface between the Hadoop cluster and the outside network. This node/host will have all the libraries and client components present, as well as current configuration of the cluster to connect to the hdfs.
This [thread](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/How-to-create-an-Edge-Node-when-creating-a-cloudera-cluster/td-p/23220) discusses same