# How to understand "hdfs client" in the process of file read and file write?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distributed-system

When we consider the process of file read and file write in hdfs, we will use the classic graph([such as the process of file write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy9kK.png)) to explain the process. As I am a beginner for hadoop, I have some trouble in the concept of "hdfs client".

My understanding about "hdfs client" as follows. Is the Client only refer to the machine or the DFSClient API or the program that the user write? When we write data to the hdfs, how end user informs the Client, by hadoop shell?

Please give me some detail explanation about the concept of "hdfs client".

Answer (score 0):

It is an interface.HDFS client interacts with Namenode and Datanode on behalf of user to fulfil user request. User establishes communication with HDFS through File System API and normal I/O operations, processing of user request and providing response over it is carried out by File System API processes.

Refer this

[What does "Client" exactly mean for Hadoop / HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221993/what-does-client-exactly-mean-for-hadoop-hdfs)